# Problem With A Subview To Window Iphone sdk 4

Tags: objective-c, iphone

The following code is in my "switchviewcontroller.m" file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    MainView *mainController=[[MainView alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"Blue View" bundle:nil];

    self.mainViewController=mainController;
    [self.view  insertSubview: mainController atIndex:0];
    [mainController release];


    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

All I am trying to do here is load this view "main" into the view in my mainwindow.

The code just gives a warning and compiles, but when it executes it crashes on the line in warning

```
//80: warning: incompatible Objective-C types 'struct MainView *', expected 'struct UIView *' when //passing argument 1 of 'insertSubview:atIndex:' from distinct Objective-C type
[self.view  insertSubview: mainController atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to insert a `UIViewController`, not a `UIView` as `insertSubview` is expecting.

Try this:

```
[self.view  insertSubview: mainController.view atIndex:0];
```